# How to write resolve service in $stateProvider in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I need to resolve a service while routing to other state using **State Provider** in **angular**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried doing some of the ways but didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use resolve object in $stateProvider while routing to other state.
 For Example :

```
    resolve: {
resolvedTheme: ['ThemeService', function (ThemeService) {
return ThemeService.get();
}]
}
```

Here:
Resolve is a service name and this is returning a callback function.